# Как получить элементы с атрибутом style="display: none"

Tags: javascript, jquery

элементы с атрибутом style="display: none"?

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div style="display: none">3</div>
<div style="display: none">4</div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('div[style*="display: none"]').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});

// Или так

$('div:hidden').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div style="display: none">3</div>
<div style="display: none">4</div>
```

Comment: для `display:none` без пробела, надо полагать, не будет ничего?

Answer (score 2):

На чистом JS

```js
let els = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0, el; el = els[i]; i++) {
    if (getComputedStyle(el).display == 'none') {
        // сюда попадаем если такие элементы найдены
        el.style.display = 'block';
        el.style.color = 'red';
    }
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div style="display: none">3</div>
<div style="display: none">4</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let hiddenElements = [...document.querySelectorAll('div')].filter(el => el.style.display == 'none');
console.log(hiddenElements)

// второй вариант менее надежн, потому что лишние пробелы или их отсутствие в строке атрибута выдадут неверный результат.
let hiddenElements1 = [...document.querySelectorAll('div[style="display: none"]')]
console.log(hiddenElements1)
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div style="display: none">3</div>
<div style="display: none">4</div>
```